# nullity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If **A** ,is an n x m matrix and **B** is an m x n matrix, then nullity(**AB**) =
nullity(**BA**).

Determine if the statement is true.

For this question, how do I go about finding the solution? What's the thought process? I never get the type of questions where the required answer is to prove a statement right or wrong, it feels like plain guess and check.

Comment: $AB$ is an $n\times n$ matrix when $BA$ is an $m\times m$ matrix

Comment: @marwalix what does that show? Does the size of the matrix tell you anything about the rank of the matrix?

Comment: Consider $A=[1,0,0,0,0]$ and $B=A^T$.  In the one case you'll have the product be $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\\vdots\\0&&\dots&&0\end{bmatrix}$ and in the other case you'll have the product be $[1]$

Comment: Counterexamples also exist for square matrices. Consider $2 \times 2$ matrices with $0$-$1$ entries

Comment: In general, spotting such a counterexample and using marwalix's hint... you should have had your attention drawn by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Think of the matrix as a linear map one is from $\Bbb{K}^m$ and one is from $\Bbb{R}^n$. So if $n\neq m$...

Comment: Generally speaking for problems of this type, I'd begin by trying to prove that it's true, or at least trying to identify reasons why it might be true. In this case you run into roadblocks early on (for example marwallx's hint). Then it's just a question of finding an example. And yes, often, when there are counterexamples, they are not unique, and choices are involved in creating them, so there's no one "right answer" or recipe that will get you to the same example as someone else.  It's not something that is instinctive, but getting used to it helps a lot. It gets easier with practice.

Comment: @leslietownes I see, thanks for the help. I'll give it a shot, I have always done it the other way with limited success.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=m=2$ and

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0\\
   0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \
B:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\
   0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}$$

Then we have $AB=0$ but $BA \ne 0$.This shows that

$$nullity(AB)  \ne  nullity(BA).$$